# Gimp used to have a Save-for-Web or Export-for-Web menu item. It's gone

Tags: gimp

On my previous computer and Debian Jessie, *Gimp* had this menu item in the `File menu`.

It was extremely important to me. You could track the output file size while adjusting image quality parameters, the file type (it offered JPEG, PNG and GIF), and seeing a preview of the result.

In Debian 9 / Gimp 2.8.18, this item is missing. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a [separate plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/33/).

On Ubuntu it is part of the `gimp-plugin-registry package`. If you want to look for it in your repos/packages the executable name is `webexport`.

Comment: Excellent - this package also exists in Debian.